# ¿Como obtener solamente la hora?

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando sacar los "ceros" como muestra la imagen

Tengo la siguiente parte de la consulta:

```
"sec_to_time(SUM(horas_semana)*3600) as horas_semana"
```

Lo cual no se de que otra forma lo puedo hacer para solo mostrar las "48" horas solamente.

¿Algún consejo?

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: sacar los ceros para verlos en donde?

Answer (score 2):

Debes definir el formato de salida. Algo asi:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(sec_to_time(SUM(horas_semana)*3600) as horas_semana,'%H') FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Para sacar únicamente la hora, minutos y segundos seria:

```
SELECT TIME(NOW())
```

aunque también podrías utilizar la función DATE_FORMAT():

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), "%H:%I:%S" )

SELECT TIME_FORMAT(sec_to_time(SUM(horas_semana)*3600) as horas_semana,'%H') FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo *"sacar"* como quitar (no mostrar), entonces buscas que el resultado de la consulta solo muestre la cantidad de horas *sin* minutos y segundos.

Como se ha sugerido en las respuestas de @federhico y @SoftMolina, puedes usar la función `TIME_FORMAT` indicando la mascarilla para las horas `%H`:

```
TIME_FORMAT(sec_to_time(SUM(horas_semana) * 3600), '%H') as horas_semana
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la funcion [**`HOUR`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour).

> Devuelve la hora. El rango del valor de retorno es de `0` a `23` para los valores de hora del día. Sin embargo, el rango de valores de `TIME` en realidad es mucho mayor, por lo que `HOUR` puede devolver valores mayores que `23`.

Ejemplo:

```
mysql> select HOUR(sec_to_time(SUM(horas_semana)*3600)) as horas_semana;
+--------------+
| horas_semana |
+--------------+
|           48 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```